# Pinescript - EMA cross & Stochastic cross

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write some code in Pinescript on when the 9 EMA crosses the 20 EMA to show the long strategy. Inversely, I'd like to show the short strategy when the 20 EMA crosses the 9 EMA. This seems to work fine for me.

Where I'm having trouble is show like a second long.strategy when the stochastic RSI is showing long, but I only want the statement to be true if the 9 EMA has crossed the 20 EMA.

Here's my code:

```
    //@version=2
strategy("Isaac Signals2", overlay=true)

//ema
ema3 = ema(close,9)
ema4 = ema(close,20)
long_ema = crossover(ema3,ema4)
short_ema = crossover(ema4,ema3)

//stochrsi
smoothK = input(3, minval=1)
smoothD = input(3, minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")

rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)

data = (60-k[1])/2
data2 = (k[1]-40)/2

long_stoch = k[1] >= d[1] and k[2] <= d[2] and k <= 60 and k >= 10
short_stoch = k[1] <= d[1] and k[2] >= d[2] and k >= 40 and k <= 95

//entries
if (long_ema) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
**if (long_ema and long_stoch)
    strategy.entry("buy+1", strategy.long)**
if (short_ema) 
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
```

Where I have it bolded above is where I'm struggling. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help

```
//@version=2
strategy("Isaac Signals2", overlay=true)

//ema
ema3 = ema(close,9)
ema4 = ema(close,20)
long_ema = crossover(ema3,ema4)
short_ema = crossover(ema4,ema3)

//stochrsi
smoothK = input(3, minval=1)
smoothD = input(3, minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")

rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)

data = (60-k[1])/2
data2 = (k[1]-40)/2

long_stoch = k[1] >= d[1] and k[2] <= d[2] and k <= 60 and k >= 10
short_stoch = k[1] <= d[1] and k[2] >= d[2] and k >= 40 and k <= 95

//entries
if (long_ema) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
if (ema3 > ema4 and long_stoch) // ema3 > ema4 means that crossover was already and uptrend is continuing 
    strategy.entry("buy+1", strategy.long)
if (short_ema) 
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty close to what I want. I want to show the first long signal (the first if statement) and then show secondary or third long signals when the stochastic RSI shows long after the ema crosses. This doesn't exactly do that but it's close.

Comment: I would recommend that you formulate your rule for entering a long position more clearly and unambiguously. Maybe you want to pyramiding your long position?

Comment: Yes exactly! Im not verse in pine script. I didn't realize you could do that. how would I be able to do this?

Comment: strategy("Isaac Signals2", overlay=true, **pyramiding  = 10**)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I've been wanting. Thank you!